# Django 1.5: UserCreationForm & Custom Auth Model

Tags: django, django-models, python-3.x, django-forms

I'm using Django 1.5 & Python 3.2.3.

I've got a custom Auth setup, which uses an email address instead of a username. There's **no username** defined in the model at all. That works fine. Yet, when I build a user creation form, it adds in a username field anyway. So I tried defining exactly which fields I want displayed, but it's still forcing a username field into the form anyway.... *even tho it doesn't even exist in the custom auth model*. How can I make it stop doing that?

My form for this is defined like so:

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyUsr
        fields = ('email','fname','surname','password1','password2',
                  'activation_code','is_active')
```

At the docs, the [Custom Users and Builtin Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms) says it "Must be re-written for any custom user model." and I think that's what I'm doing here. Neither this, nor the [UserCreationForm documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) say anything more about this though. So I don't know what I'm missing. I didn't find anything via Google either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create your form from sctratch, it should not extend the UserCreationForm. The UserCreationForm have a username field explicitly defined in it as well as some other fields. You can look at it [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L66).

Comment: Ugh, for all the good about Django, this is a crazy bad bit. They allow a custom auth to be made with no username, but it breaks the UserCreationForm. Thanks. at least I know I'm not doing something wrong to get the result I was getting.

Comment: But the docs says that this form should be rewritten. And rewrite doesnt mean extends from it, it means a new one

Answer (score 15):

Your `UserCreationForm` should look something like

```
# forms.py
from .models import CustomUser

class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Password confirmation", widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUserModel
        # Note - include all *required* CustomUser fields here,
        # but don't need to include password1 and password2 as they are
        # already included since they are defined above.
        fields = ("email",)

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            msg = "Passwords don't match"
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password mismatch")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

You'll also want a user change form, which won't overrwrite the password field:

```
class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser

    def clean_password(self):
        # always return the initial value
        return self.initial['password']
```

Define these in your admin like this:

```
#admin.py

from .forms import UserChangeForm, UserAddForm

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    form = UserChangeForm
```

You'll also need to override `list_display`, `list_filter`, `search_fields`, `ordering`, `filter_horizontal`, `fieldsets`, and `add_fieldsets` (everything in `django.contrib.auth.admin.UserAdmin` that mentions `username`, I think I listed all of it).

Comment: TwoScoops in save method looks funny :)

Comment: Where can i find this TwoScoopsUserCreationForm ?