# username error using custom authentication in django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to create custom authentication in Django where the identifier is an email, there is a required field called name and a password field. The login view works fine, but I get an error `username` from the forms.

Here is my views.py

```
def auth_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/tasks/")
        else:           
            return HttpResponse('Invalid login.')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, "registration/login.html", {
        'form': form,
    })

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            new_user = authenticate(email=request.POST['email'], password=request.POST['password1'])
            login(request, new_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/tasks/")
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, "registration/register.html", {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Here is my register.html

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form" method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create an account</h2>
    <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="30" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
    <br>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="password1" maxlength="4096" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="password2" maxlength="4096" class="form-control" placeholder="Password confirmation" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/tasks/" />
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Create the account</button>
</form>

{% if form.errors %}
    {% for error in form.errors %}
            {{ error }}                     
        {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

This prints the error `username`. What's wrong here?

Comment: There is no `username` field in the html form, that might be required in `UserCreationForm`.

Comment: How would a register view work in case of in a case of a custom authentication system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create your own form instead of using django's own `UserCreationForm`. Django's form requires you to have a username.

You don't have a username, so Django's form will not work for you. So... create your own. See also [Django 1.5: UserCreationForm & Custom Auth Model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16562529/27401), and especially the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16570743/27401 .